# It is false that if p then q.

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm doing some homework in which I'm converting textual descriptions of logic statements to their respective symbolic representation.

If one reads `It is false that if p then q`.

I was wondering the typical representation of this.

i.e. Is it `~p -> q` or `~(p -> q)`. Essentially what I'm asking is typically when converting a textual representation to a symbolic representation, do we assume that the negation applies to the entire expression, or simply the entity immediately following the negation.

Thanks.

Comment: The second one is right.

Comment: Negations only apply to well-formed formulas, or expressions which can get rendered into well-formed formulas (check the formation rules).  So, a negation can only apply to an entire expression, NOT an entity which immediately follows it, since the entity immediately following a negation could be a word like "if" or "both", or what follows $\lnot$ could be a parenthesis symbol or something else also.  The formation rules tell us that a negation only applies to an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it as

*It is false that: "if $p$, then $q$".*

So the (entire) statement $(p\implies q)$ should be logically negated.

Comment: Is that a commonly accepted convention? Or just a personal interpretation? Any references?

Comment: "If p, then q" means (p $\rightarrow$ q).  So, we have the negation of (p $\rightarrow$ q), $\lnot$(p $\rightarrow$ q).  The entity that follows the expression is "if", which only stops after the "then ...".  The negation applies to the string of characters such that that string qualifies as a wff.  For instance, if we use polish notation we could write $\lnot$$\rightarrow$pq.  But, we build wffs up from the atoms, so $\rightarrow$pq is a wff, and thus the $\lnot$ must apply $\rightarrow$pq, NOT just $\rightarrow$.